# Idiomatic way to call same method on multiple objects

Tags: kotlin, idioms

Let's say I have this simplified class for a data-structure I want to use.
How can I make the clear() function more concise and idiomatic? calling clear one both fields and super seperately seems  redundant. I know that one could normally create a list of the object, but that isn't possible with super.

```
class NewList<E>() : ArrayList<E>() {

    private val x = LinkedList<E>()
    private val y = HashSet<E>()

    override fun clear() {
        x.clear()
        y.clear()
        super.clear()
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no better solution

Comment: HashSet is not a list. So what you want to do is call clear on `x` and `super` at the same time because they are the same data structure aka list. Now, `x` is local and `super` is of course super. They are also two different things from syntax perspective. If they were both local variables, maybe you could have created some generic extension function that takes in lists as args, iterates on them in a loop and calls `list::clear` or something. Unfortunately for your case there is no better solution as IR42 stated above. Also, calling `clear` like that is not that bad. Readability > conciseness

Comment: @sonnet They are both `MutableCollection`.

Comment: You can't do much about the `super` call, because it _isn't_ a call of the method on another object; but you can group the others together by creating a list, as you say. If there are only two of them, it's probably not worth it, if more it might be.